# Asymptotic of reciprocal sums of $k-$almost primes

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

As in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515568/do-we-know-the-rate-of-divergence-of-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-the-k-almost-pr) previous question, let a $k-$almost prime be a positive integer having exactly $k$ prime factors, not necessarily distinct. Let $\mathbb{P}_k$ be the set of the $k$-almost primes and let
$$
\rho_k(n):=\sum\limits_{\substack{q\in \mathbb{P_k}\\q\le n}}\frac1q.
$$
The answer to that question states that (I presume for fixed $k$) the asymptotic estimate for $\rho_k(n)$ has leading term
$$
\rho_k(n) \asymp \frac{1}{k!}(\log \log n)^k, 
$$
and error term of $O((\log \log n)^{k-1}).$

How would a rigorous proof showing the error term proceed?

Is there a reference to such a result in the literature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just focusing on the error term since the main term was already discussed in your previous question.
You know that
$$
\sum_{p\leq n}\frac1{p} = \log\log n + O(1)\;;
$$
then
$$
\rho_k(n) \ll \left(\sum_{p\leq n}\frac1{p}\right)^k =
O((\log\log n)^k) + O((\log\log n)^{k-1}) \;.
$$

Comment: The exponent should be $k$ not n in your first equation after "then"? How do you rigorously argue the error term?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, of course the exponent is $k$. Concerning your second question, you have something like $(\log\log n + O(1))^k$, the main term is the product of $k$ $\log\log n$, the main error comes from $k$ product like $O((log\log n)^{k-1})O(1)=O((log\log n)^{k-1})$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm that with the linked question's answer and your answer, it has been established that  $$\rho_k(n) \asymp ( \log \log n)^k$$

Comment: @kodlu Confirmed!