# What are the asymptotics of sums like $\frac16+\frac1{10}+\frac1{14}+\frac1{15}+\frac1{21}+\cdots+\frac1{p_{n-1}p_n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I've recently bumped into [this old question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515568/do-we-know-the-rate-of-divergence-of-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-the-k-almost-pr) and I was wondering about the sum running over only numbers with distinct prime factors. More precisely:

> For $k,n\ge1$ let $S_{k,n}$ be the set of numbers whose factorization
>   contains exactly $k$ distinct primes out of the first $n$ ones. So,
>   for instance: $S_{1,n}=\{2,3,...,p_n\};$
>   $S_{2,n}=\{6,10,...,2p_n,15,21,...,3p_n,...,p_{n-1}p_n\}.$

With both $k$ and $n$ allowed to vary, are the asymptotics of $$\sum_{m\in S_{k,n}} \frac1m$$ known? Up to what order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For convenience I will use a slightly different notation.

Meissel-Mertens second theorem gives for the sum over primes $p \leq n$ that
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \sum_{p \leq n} \frac{1}{p} - \ln(\ln n)\right) = M$$

In other words asymptotically
$$ \sum_{p \leq n} \frac{1}{p} \approx \ln(\ln n)$$

If we square the expression we get

$$ \left(\sum_{p \leq n} \frac{1}{p} \right)^2 = \sum_{p \leq n} \frac{1}{p^2} + \sum_{p_1 \neq p_2 \leq n} \frac{1}{p_1 p_2} \approx \left[\ln(\ln n)\right]^2 $$

Since the sum $\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}$ converges, we therefor obtain
$$ \sum_{p_1 < p_2 \leq n} \frac{1}{p_1 p_2} \approx \frac{1}{2} \left[\ln(\ln n)\right]^2 $$

Taking higher powers and retaining the leading terms yields
$$ \sum_{p_1 < p_2 < \dots <p_k\leq n} \frac{1}{\prod_i^k p_i} \approx \frac{1}{k!} \left[\ln(\ln n)\right]^{~k} $$

Using the prime number theorem $p_n \sim n \ln n$ we find
$$ \sum_{m \in S_{k,n}} \frac{1}{m} \approx \frac{1}{k!} \left[\ln(\ln (n \ln n))\right]^{~k} $$

Note that this only works here because you consider all combinations with factors up to a maximum prime. A different sum would be over all primes $p$,$q$ where the product is bounded
$$ \sum_{p \neq q | p q \leq n} \frac{1}{p q}$$

Comment: So looking at how you used "$\approx$" at the begininning, in conclusion you're saying $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{m\in S_{k,n}}\frac1m - \frac1{k!} \left(\log\log(n\log n)\right)^k$ is a constant that depends on $k$?

Comment: No, it will be the leading term only. If you work out the case $k=2$ you get for instance 2 $\sum_{m \in S_{2n}} 1/m = [\ln(\ln(n \ln n))]^2 + 2 M [\ln(\ln(n \ln n))] + M^2 - \sum_{m \in S_{1n}} 1/m^2$

Comment: Ah, I see, indeed it didn't have to be that formal. Thanks!